# Are item IDs of google form's items unique through the whole gforms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

If I'd store id of one form item can this id repeat for another item in another form?

Answer (score 2):

All the item id's created in a Google form or multiple forms will be unique. However, we cannot access an item individually without referring to a particular form first.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Where you got that info?